# How to know first line or not of text file using vba

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I would like to know first line or not when reading a text file to edit its data.
Because I don't want to update that data at other lines.

I want to branch my code at the position marked using a ★.

What is the best way of doing this?

```
Set file = FSO.OpenTextFile(filepath)

Do Until file.AtEndOfStream
    line = file.ReadLine
    If ★ Then
        'edit data of first line
    ElseIf ... Then    'other lines' condition
    'update data of other lines            
    End If
    'Write line to text file        
Loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather trivial, but you'll have to do this check before reading the first line.

If you always open the file yourself, you can be sure that your first iteration is at the beginning of the file:

```
Set file = FSO.OpenTextFile(filepath)
Set firstline = True

Do Until file.AtEndOfStream
    line = file.ReadLine
    If firstline Then
        firstline = False
        'Do first line stuff
    ElseIf ...
    End If
Loop
```

If you don't know for sure that the file will indeed be at the beginning (i.e. you're not opening it yourself in that part of code):

```
Set file = FSO.OpenTextFile(filepath)

Do Until file.AtEndOfStream
    line = file.ReadLine
    If file.Line == 2 Then ' we are actually at the second line now (after reading)
        'Do first line stuff
    ElseIf ...
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. I would like to one. [file.Line] is 1 before Loop and it becomes 2 at Loop start. Therefore, if check [file.Line = 2] in the Loop, is it correct? @Mario Please explain me.

Comment: Yeah, true, my mistake. Since you've read one line already, the value will be `2` rather than `1`.